# How is possible to return a function as a property?

Tags: javascript, closures

```js
function makeFunc() {
  var name = 'Mozilla';
  function displayName() {
    alert(name);
  }
  return displayName;
}

var myFunc = makeFunc();
myFunc();
```

in the following example this inner function returned as property `return displayName;`

Comment: Please describe what the problem is.

Comment: this syntax makes me unable to figure out whether it variable or  method. i want someone to explain to me why we returned it without parentheses.

Comment: `displayName` is a variable (as is `myFunc`), `something.displayName` is a method.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a property. It is a value stored in a variable. The variable is read and the value is returned.

Functions are first-class objects in JavaScript. You can do anything with them that you can do with any other kind of object (and thus anything you can do with any other kind of value).

Comment: i am new to javascript .i don't understand you but where is this variable??
there is a property called name and a function called displayName
so there is no assignment. @Quentin

Comment: Function declarations create a variable with the same name in the scope where they appear. The variable name is `displayName`.

Comment: does this means if created function in the global scope i can call it with the same name without parentheses?

Comment: No, because by putting parentheses after the-thing-that-evaluates-to-the-function is *how* you **call** a function.

Comment: so you mean in calling i have to use parentheses but in returning i can use the name of the function.right!!

Answer (score 0):

The statement `var myFunc = makeFunc();` will execute the method makeFunc and assigns it to the variable myFunc.
The makeFunc method returns another method, so a function is assigned to the myFunc variable. This function is executed in your next statement `myFunc();` and alerts 'Mozilla'.